# Reference request: Relation between $Sp(N)$, $Spin(N) $, $SU(N)$ groups and physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, lie-algebra

I want to understand the relationship of the so common $SU(N)$ and $SO(N)$ groups in physics with the symplectic group which I think is the double cover of the first and the Spin groups $Spin(N)$.

Is there a good reference, mainly for physicists.

Comment: There is a specific answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/25980